# Set default value to elasticsearch index.max_inner_result_window parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm actually using elasticsearch 6.7 and I get an error while searching in ES :

> Top hits result window is too large, the top hits aggregator [instances]'s from + size must be less than or equal to: [100] but was [2147483647]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_inner_result_window] index level setting.

I know how to change this parameter, this is not the issue.

I actually use this to change the parameter on **existing** indexes:

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index.max_inner_result_window": "2147483647"
}
```

However, elasticsearch will not update future indexes that will be created.

My app often put documents in new indexes. If the index doesn't exist, elasticsearch creates it. However I don't want to run this request everytime a document is put inside an index.

The issue is when a new index is created when a document is put inside, it keep the default value to 100 for this index.

There is a paramter in es.yaml to set the default limit, however, it seems to be deprecated and not working.

What I want is that ES set automatically the limit to the integer max value when a new index is created without running the request each time I put a document in ES.

Thank you for reading, hope you can help me.

Regards,
Jules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try defining this in the [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) like below so that all the new index created will have this setting.

```
{
    "index_patterns": [
        "*" // note this
    ],
    "template": {
        "settings": {
            "index":{
                "max_inner_result_window": 2147483647
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try and give feedback!

Comment: @taneik cool, sure looking forward to hear from you

Comment: It actually worked, thank you, but i just had to remove the `template` object, putting `settings` in the main json object. Thank you !

Comment: Where do you put this template file? In which directory?

Comment: @Corel You will need to make an HTTP PUT call to the URL: `<es_url>/_index_template/<template_name>`
With the body containing the template mentioned in the answer.